# How to delete specific row from sql server using nodeJs

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express, tedious

I am using nodeJs as a backend language and sql server as a database. I can to delete whole table row from database but can not able to delete specific row.
Here is my code...

```
router.delete('/student/:id', function (req, res, next) {
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    request = new Request("DELETE FROM student where id=@id", function(err) {
        if (err) { console.log(err);}
    });

    request.addParameter('id');

    request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {  console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');   });
    connection.execSql(request);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be the call to `addParameter()` function with incomplete list of arguments. `request.addParameter()` expects three arguments, viz. parameter name, data type, value. You only provided the parameter name.

Try changing `request.addParameter('id');` to something like this:

```
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES; // Get the TYPES enum.
request.addParameter('id', TYPES.Int, parseInt(req.params.id)); // Assuming your id is an integer. Use proper Types enum, and conversion, if its not.
```

You can also refer the example on Microsoft website here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js